# How to stop idle(UNSENT) XmlHttpRequests from timing out in IE11?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

My program will generate a large number(thousands) of content URLs that it will then loop through, and make an ajax GET request for each.

The problem I am having is that IE can only operate on 6 requests at a time, so the remaining ones are stuck with readyState = "UNSENT". This is only problematic because some of these requests can take minutes, while others only take seconds.

Every time my program runs, right at the 300 second mark, all of the UNSENT XHR requests will timeout and throw an error in the console: `XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ee2, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ee2.`. After looking into this error, I noticed that this is essentially a network timeout.

A few things I have tried and confirmed after much testing:

- This is strictly happening in IE11 (tested in Chrome and worked good)
- I tried setting up timeouts greater than 300 seconds in multiple different forms/ways. All of them only effected the individual Ajax calls, meaning if one started and took more than my timeout(let's say ten minutes) it would timeout, but the UNSENT requests would still timeout after five minutes.
- Also tried setting timeout to 0, no effect(still threw out UNSENT requests after 300 seconds)

### Attempt 1

```
 sContentUrls.forEach(function( sContentUrl ) {
      $.get({
           url: sContentUrl,
           timeout: 600000,
           error: function() {
           },
           success: function() {
                console.log("Success");
           },
           async: true
      });
});
```

### Attempt 2

```
sContentUrls.forEach( function( sContentUrl ) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", sContentUrl, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200){
            console.log("Success"); 
        }
    };

    xhr.onprogress = function(){ };
    xhr.ontimeout = function(){ };
    xhr.onerror = function () { };
    setTimeout(function(){
        xhr.send();
    }, 0);
});
```

I am wondering what I can do to stop IE11 from throwing this error and aborting thousands of requests. I have looked into setting up a manager/queue for the requests, so that a new one is only made when it can sent right away or something.

Has anyone seen this issue before or knows of a potential workaround/solution? I can confirm that it does not occur if I make the requests synchronous, but due to the massive amount of requests this isn't a great option for me.

Thanks!